# How do I sample from a stim Tableau's stabilizer state?

Tags: stim, stabilizer-state

(Copied from https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/issues/708)

> [In stim], is there any way to directly generate the samples starting from a tableau and not a circuit?
> I understand that the standard way is to compile the sampler starting from the circuit
>
> ```python
> import stim
> c = stim.Circuit('''
>     X 2
>     M 0 1 2
> ''')
> s = c.compile_sampler()
> s.sample(shots=1)
> ```
>
> but I was wondering whether the `CompiledMeasurementSampler` it produces could be directly initialized from a tableu, and maybe the qubits one wants to measure.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the tableau into a circuit, and then sample the circuit.

```python
tableau = ...

sampling_circuit = tableau.to_circuit()
sampling_circuit.append("M", range(c.num_qubits))
sampler = sampling_circuit.compiler_sampler()

samples = sampler.sample(shots=256)
```